# Centering an image with HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I want to center image with HTML.  I have my image but am not sure how to do it?  I appreciate help.  THANKS.

Here's my code:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

Comment: Use CSS!  Using pure HTML is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the onset of HTML5, you should look to use CSS for image centering.  HTMl5 actually depreciated the align tag.

Try the following CSS code instead:

```
<IMG id="myImage" src="image.jpg" >
<style type="text/css">
    #myImage {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

super easy - simply wrap it in a container and give the left and right margins auto width

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vc3rY/1/

```
.container {width: 300px; background: #f2f2f2; margin: 0 auto}
```

Answer (score 0):

An image is an inline-boxe, so text-align:center; on parent should be the basic way to do it.

If you display:block, your image , then it will be margin:auto; and it will be the only one thing on that line ... if no floatting elements ahead in the flow.
(always nice to understand how it worksfrom 101 CSS rules :) )

Answer (score 0):

< center>
--YOUR IMAGE INFO--
< /center

Note that this will center you image horizontally to the middle of the page.

If you want to center it vertically or align it to the text you will have to use a different method.

Comment: <center> is deprecated. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center?retiredLocale=it)